# Python script to read single value from MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just need to read a single value from an MS SQL Server 2008 connection, but I'm not sure how to do this. Here is the code

```
import pyodbc



querystring = """SELECT USER_NAME
FROM sem6.sem_computer, [sem6].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], sem6.IDENTITY_MAP, sem6.SEM_CLIENT
WHERE [sem6].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
AND sem6.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
AND sem6.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
"""

con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.10.10.100;DATABASE=databasename;UID=username;PWD=password')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(querystring)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch the result after executing the query.  See [PEP 249](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) for how the dbapi exposes this.

In your case, `username = cur.fetchone()[0]` will work.

Answer (score 3):

According to python's DB-API, you need to do fetchone to retrieve the first row:

```
import pyodbc



querystring = """SELECT USER_NAME
FROM sem6.sem_computer, [sem6].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], sem6.IDENTITY_MAP, sem6.SEM_CLIENT
WHERE [sem6].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
AND sem6.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
AND sem6.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
"""

con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.10.10.100;DATABASE=databasename;UID=username;PWD=password')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(querystring)
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row[0])
con.close()
```